# grab the data rows from the table which created within last hour with where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, intervals

I have a data table like this

```
|-----------------------------------------------------------------|
| Id   |  OrderId |  Description   | CreatedAt                    |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------|
| 1    |  001     |  order desc 1  | Sat Apr 30 17:42:00 IST 2022 |
| 2    |  002     |  order desc 2  | Sat Apr 30 17:55:00 IST 2022 |
| 3    |  003     |  order desc 3  | Sat Apr 30 18:04:00 IST 2022 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

All the columns are varchar/string type. I want a query to grab only those rows which are create in last 1 hour only. I have created one query for this but its return blank result

```
SELECT Id FROM TABLE WHERE CAST(CreatedAt as datetime) > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
```

I dont know if the query is incorrect or there something i need to modify in it.

Comment: When you say you don't know if the query is correct, does it mean you haven't run it? Would be helpful if we know what happens when you run this

Comment: @CedricIpkiss i have run it and it run successfully but not giving any row in return.
I have checked it by adding row with latest time but always it return empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your `CreatedAt` column is actually text.  If you want to convert it to a datetime column, you will first have to use `STR_TO_DATE()` with an appropriate format mask.

```sql
SELECT Id
FROM yourTable
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(CreatedAt, '%a %b %d %H:%i:%s IST %Y') > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR;
```

Comment: It returns me last 3 hours of rows, or it looks like that it return the current date rows

Comment: Please check the data in your table, as I believe my general logic to be correct.

Comment: @HarishKumar you can easily test the solution https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4c9f750dd1f1d37115a827846b281c1b  and it works fine . Maybe it should be `>=` instead of `>`

Comment: yes @Tim Biegeleisen your query is working, i tried in a new database and table. I think there is some other issue with the existing table where i am trying this query.